# In a Nodejs app how do I make an HTTP client request inside an Express method

Tags: node.js, http, express

When a browser or curl client calls my node express app, I want to fetch JSON data from an external website and return it, however despite seeing the nested http call return the JSON data back to my express server I'm battling to get the JSON to return to the calling browser - how do I do this?

Here is the current test app code with curl response:

```
var http = require('http');
var app = require('express')();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

  var str = '';

  var options = {
    host: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
    path: '/posts/1'
  };

  callback = function(response) {
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
      str += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function () {
      console.log(str);
    });
  }

  var req = http.request(options, callback);

  res.send(str);
  req.end();
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Here is the result of CURL localhost:3000 (no body data returned):
[image]

The server side console log's show the http request data has been received:
[image]

All suggestions/pointers appreciated!

Comment: If you are trying to just reply back with whatever you received then ```app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.status(200).send(req.body);
});``` will send that complete json that you have on your server side, back to client.

Comment: Thanks Vikram - I'll try that. What would I need to do to modify  the response before returning it the callee?

Comment: Hi Vikram, sorry I couldn't get this working, I suspect it's the waiting for completion issue again but fortunately some working answers have been received in the meantime. Thanks anyhow!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just as an alternative (the answer provided by m-a-r-c-e-l-i-n-o will work just fine), you can shorten your code (and save a bit of memory) by using the [streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) provided by both Express and `http.request()`, like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  http.request('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', function(response) {
    response.pipe(res);
  }).on('error', function(e) {
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }).end();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

It appears that you need to wait for the nested response to come back before sending out the actual response, like so:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

  var str = '';

  var options = {
    host: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
    path: '/posts/1'
  };

  var callback = function(response) {
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
      str += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function () {
      console.log(str);
      res.send(str); // SEND ACTUAL RESPONSE HERE
    });
  }

  var req = http.request(options, callback);
  req.end();

});
```

Otherwise, you are sending `str` right away and it's empty, thus why you can't see it.

Comment: The `req.end()` should still be at the bottom of the handler function, otherwise the HTTP request won't be made.

Comment: @robertklep yep, honest mistake, placed it back 2 minutes ago!

Comment: Thanks Marcelino - that makes perfect sense! Will try that out shortly.

Comment: Great :) While we're at it: `callback` should be declared properly as well (`var callback`), otherwise it becomes a global which may cause issues.

Comment: @robertklep good tip!
Joelster, consider marking this answer as "correct" (by clicking the check mark on the top-left of the question) if you felt that it has addressed your concerns.